# Why is the exact calculation solution slower than binary search solution?

Tags: javascript

So I tried doing this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/arranging-coins/

After doing some math, I came up with this solution:

```js
var arrangeCoins = function(n) {
    return parseInt((Math.sqrt(8*n+1)-1)/2);
};
```

This does return the right answer. However, I noticed that it is literally the bottom of the barrel when it comes to execution speed. Comparatively, the alternative solution, where binary search is used to search for the right value in the range of 1 to n is around 2 to 3 times faster than mine. So something like this:

```js
var arrangeCoins = function(n) {
    
    let left = 1;           
    let right = n;          
    
    while(left + 1 < right){
        let mid = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);
        let sum = (mid + 1) * mid / 2  
        
        if(sum === n){
            return mid;
        }else if(sum < n){
            left = mid;
        }else{
            right = mid;
        }
    }
          
    return (right + 1) * right / 2 === n? right : left;
}
```

Compared to my solution, this has the time complexity of O(log n), which would mean it should have been slower, at least in theory.

Why is this the case? What can I do to improve the execution speed of my solution?

Comment: parseInt(0.0000005) == 5

Answer (score 1):

This is not an authoritative answer but:

1. sqrt is relatively slow
2. it looks like your parseInt is useless and wastes time

Comment: I can see 1 being a thing, but as for 2, the question required the return value to be int, so yeah it has to be there, although I guess using bit shifting instead would have save me some executing time.

Comment: @randomguy parseInt converts the input to a **string** first. You're looking for Math.round or Math.floor.

Comment: Yeah, my point was that parseInt is made to parse an int from a string.

I can't find the source code but when you use parseInt on a number this is what I think happens (roughly):

 - it checks the type of the argument, number in your case

 - it uses the argument's method for conversion to string, probably itoa for number arguments

 - it converts that string to a number, probably with atoi

Even if I'm wrong and their implementation is a hundred times smarter than mine, rounding down will definitely be faster.